# Create a Swift class in Objective-C by name

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am working through an issue where I have a mixed code base and creation paradigm where a single class (in Objective-C) has the names of all classes I can create and use.

Previously the code base was completely Objective-C so when I had a name of a class I needed to create I simply went:

```
- (Class)sourceClass {
    return NSClassFromString(sourceClassName);
}
```

Now I have to support returning Swift classes. I have tried using the bundle name with a dot in front of the class. This did not work (returns nil):

```
NSString *appName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleName"];
NSString *classStringName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", appName, sourceClassName];
return NSClassFromString(classStringName);
```

I also tried some crazy formatting I found online, also returned nil:

```
NSString *appName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleName"];
NSString *classStringName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"_TtC%lu%@%lu%@", appName.length, appName, sourceClassName.length, sourceClassName];
return NSClassFromString(classStringName);
```

Comment: Where does Swift come into this?

Comment: the class I am trying to load is a swift class

Comment: Has the Swift class been exposed to Objective-C using `@objc`?

Comment: I have tried it with and without @objc in front of the class

Comment: You may want to check if `appName` returned by `objectForInfoDictionaryKey` is not `nil`.  Absence of `@objc` should not prevent you from getting a `Class` from `NSClassFromString`.  Try hard-coding the application name just to see if it works; do something like `NSClassFromString(@"MyAppName.MySwiftClassName")`.

Comment: I gave this a try (with many formatting combinations found else ware online like i said above), for some reason even hard coded everything was returning nil from NSClassFromString.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to mix and match Objective-C and Swift using runtimes like this is going to be very problematic. For a start all of your Swift classes and any properties or functions you need will have to be exposed to Objective-C. Next as you've discovered there's the naming issues. The best way to check the names will be to do a quick classes dump of all the classes in the project. Here's some bit's of code from one of my projects that scans a bundle for classes:

```
 // Get a reference to your main bundle or the bundle where the Swift classes are.
CFBundle * bundle = //....
NSURL *executableURL = (NSURL *) CFBridgingRelease(CFBundleCopyExecutableURL(bundle));
if (executableURL) {

    STLog(self, @"Scanning executable: %@", executableURL);

    unsigned int count = 0;
    const char** classes = objc_copyClassNamesForImage(executable, &count);
    STLog(self, @"Found %i classes", count);
    if (count == 0) {
        return;
    }

    for(unsigned int i = 0;i < count;i++) {
        Class nextClass = objc_getClass(classes[i]);
        // Print the class name here
    }
}
```

Using something like that should help you to ensure you can see the classes you're after and get their names correct.

Finally though, what concerns me about the description of your code is the concept of using a single class as a factory for everything else. This sounds like an extremely limiting and problematic design. I'd suggest you take a moment to sit back and reassess if it's really a good idea.

Comment: Thank you for your input drekka, the reason this exists is very long winded but in short the app can be customized many times over and the class is used to link providers with implementations (lets say I have 4 map services, I can build in a single implementation and based on build configuration will find the correct provider and be ok with it). This system was set up pre swift and is now being worked on to support swift so it is a viable option to rework. I am going to mess around with your code above to see what I have access to in Swift and in Objective c. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Ok so i used this snip-it and i learned that there is more complexity hahaha but this helped with the solution. Each feature is in its own cocoapod so the "bundle" changes based on what pod the class exists on. So its "cocoapodName.className" for a swift class and "className" for an objective c class. Your snip-it helped a lot thank you very much